# Modify privacy settings for Album via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, acl, privacy

Well, it's been a few months since I saw someone else ask so thought I might give it a try.

I am writing an application which depends heavily on the ability to change an album's privacy after-the-fact - but unfortunately deleting the album and recreating won't work for me as I want to keep comments and tags in-tact. From what I see FB still only allows setting an album's privacy on-create and does not provide a way to modify this setting later. (And no options for per-picture privacy settings, which would be extra great as well if also modifiable.)

Dear Facebook - any luck on having this feature added? Or any thoughts about a workaround? (Perhaps by programmatically creating lists and changing those/etc, doesn't sound very clean though.)

Thanks...

Comment: Since Facebook employees do not seem to regularly check Stack Overflow, I would recommend that you file this feature on Facebook's bugtracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I'm here almost every day TBH
That said, this clearly is off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @Igy - Happy to have you here with us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API that provides that feature, Facebook's own interface is the only way to retroactively change privacy settings